# Is it acceptable to ask for the answer of an online course assignment?

Tags: discussion

I Google-searched "pandas corr" and the third result was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579908/use-corr-to-get-the-correlation-between-two-columns), which solicits (and receives) the exact answer to an assignment ([Question #9](https://www.coursera.org/learn/python-data-analysis/notebook/KSSjT/assignment-3)) I'm working on. Kind of ruins the fun.

This is the question:

> Question 9 (6.6%) Create a column that estimates the number of citable
>   documents per person. What is the correlation between the number of
>   citable documents per capita and the energy supply per capita? Use the
>   .corr() method, (Pearson's correlation).

I can see how it's a relatively straightforward question with a broadly applicable answer, and it's efficient to waste energy obscuring the context, and the question received numerous upvotes; so maybe this is how SO is supposed to work. I'm just curious so I know for the future in my own asking/answering.

Comment: Yes, if we can't tell that that is what is occurring. In other words, if it's phrased and researched such that it's a valid SO question, it's a valid SO question. if it isn't, it isn't. It doesn't really matter whether or not it's from an assignment.

Comment: Sadly, exam and assignment cheating is common on SO:(  Luckily, such questions, though acceptable in principle, are very often bad in other ways and so get downvoted/closed, (occasionally, before someone answers and that answer can be copy/pasted out).

Comment: How should reviewer/moderator know that the problem comes from an online course? Could as well be a assignment at a school or a real world problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If a question is a good quality, not too broad, not opinion-based, etc and it asks an answerable question, then yes it is welcome here.

We don't really care if the question is about homework (unless you expect us to do all the work). The fact it *"kind of ruins [your] fun"* is not our problem, and if you don't want something like this to ruin the fun, then by all means **don't read the answers**.

Comment: or don't google it to begin with!

Comment: I didn't google the question--I googled "pandas corr"!!

Comment: I do have to say, I'm not entirely sure I'd consider the linked question as a good question. On the surface it looks pretty OK, it is clear, well presented and formatted, but it does seem like the poster is expecting us to do all the real work. On the other hand, it did yield some good answers.

Comment: But please be aware that a lot of users will downvote your question anyways. If you are smart you either don't mention that it is homework, or you link to any of the answers here and state that you made sure this question is OK on SO

Comment: @LonelyNeuron: sometimes there is no escaping that. If someone has a problem with a sorting algorithm implementation, there is *always* somebody quick to comment (or even answer!) "use `qsort`". Notes such as "I cannot use *x*"  are too often met with comments "why can't you?" – I do that as well if no reason is given.